# OS x El capitan 10.11 - Virtualbox - Missing Bluetooth Controller Transport

Tags: windows, macos, virtualbox, osx-elcapitan

I downloaded an image for OS X El capitan 10.11 to start it on windows 10 via virtualBox 5.1.14, after starting it, it hangs at the error  "Missing Bluetooth Controller Transport" as appears in the snapshot, I searched the internet for a solution but I failed.

[OS x VM starting Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEr6u.png)

Comment: You cannot legally run OS X as a VM on Windows. Do not ask about software piracy here.

Answer (score 14):

1: Create the cmd file:

```
cd "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\"

VBoxManage.exe modifyvm "Mac OS" --cpuidset 00000001 000106e5 00100800 0098e3fd bfebfbff

VBoxManage setextradata "Mac OS" "VBoxInternal/Devices/efi/0/Config/DmiSystemProduct" "iMac11,3"

VBoxManage setextradata "Mac OS" "VBoxInternal/Devices/efi/0/Config/DmiSystemVersion" "1.0"

VBoxManage setextradata "Mac OS" "VBoxInternal/Devices/efi/0/Config/DmiBoardProduct" "Iloveapple"

VBoxManage setextradata "Mac OS" "VBoxInternal/Devices/smc/0/Config/DeviceKey" "ourhardworkbythesewordsguardedpleasedontsteal(c)AppleComputerInc"

VBoxManage setextradata "Mac OS" "VBoxInternal/Devices/smc/0/Config/GetKeyFromRealSMC" 1
```

2: Replace “Mac OS” with your virtual machine name

3: Shut down the VM software completely and then run cmd file as admin.

4: Start VM software and start the vm

Comment: remind for time saving: Shut down the VM software completely and then run cmd file as admin.

Comment: Can confirm this helped boot an old HDD from a core 2 duo iMac running Maverick.  The HDD is being run as raw for direct access.

Answer (score -2):

what worked for me was the tutorial from where I copy pasted had -- and "" copied as a weird characters once I changed that and executed in the CMD window it worked

Comment: when you mention an external tutorial you should always copy-paste the answer part, but if not at least post a link so you're answer won't be 100% useless.... here's the link I assumed you were talking about https://techsviewer.com/how-to-fix-missing-bluetooth-controller-transport-on-virtualbox/